# Problem when posting json data with python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm trying to get all my submitted code from LeetCode-CN, and I need to get the translation of the problems. The folling curl command can give me the desired result:

`curl 'https://leetcode-cn.com/graphql' -H 'authority: leetcode-cn.com'  -H 'origin: https://leetcode-cn.com' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'referer: https://leetcode-cn.com/problemset/all/' --data '{"operationName":"getQuestionTranslation","variables":{},"query":"query getQuestionTranslation($lang: String) {\n  translations: allAppliedQuestionTranslations(lang: $lang) {\n    title\n    questionId\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}'`

But the following python code can't work:

```py
def loadChnProblemList(client):
    query = {
        "operationName": "getQuestionTranslation", 
        "variables": {}, 
        "query": "query getQuestionTranslation($lang: String) {\n  translations: allAppliedQuestionTranslations(lang: $lang) {\n    title\n    questionId\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application-json",
        "origin": "https://leetcode-cn.com",
        "referer": "https://leetcode-cn.com/problemset/all/"
    }
    response = requests.post("https://leetcode-cn.com/graphql", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(query))
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    print(data)
```

The server will respond:

`{"errors":[{"message":"Must provide query string."}]}'`

Why the curl command works but the python code doesn't?

Comment: Try get instead of post

Comment: The `curl` command line is clearly making a `POST` request.

Comment: change `content-type` to  `application/json`,

Comment: @Shijith is correct, i never thought it's a such tiny mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shijith is correct - changing the content-type to application/json is the fix. See [requests docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for more details.